# App launch sequencer

Tags: automation

Every morning when I get into work I launch about a dozen apps and whatnot (FF, TB, VSx2-3, Eclipse, SSH, SVN update x2-3). Needles to say this does a good job of warming up my HDD for the day. I rather suspect that it would run a lot faster if they were launched sequentially (not to mention that I wouldn't need to click in 17 different places).

*Is there a preexisting product that can kick off a sequence of tasks/apps/etc. where each task is only started after the last app is done hammering the HDD?*

It would nerd to be able to kick apps like VS and firefox and also be able to trigger explorer context menu items like SVN update in TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 2):

Try [SlickRun](http://www.bayden.com/SlickRun/1033/SlickRunHelp.htm), it's free, I've used it for years, I use it constantly and I'd be lost without it.

Think of it like a configurable Start->Run command, it'll do what you want (you can configure n second pauses between multiple commands), and if you install it you'll use it for a thousand different things before the first week is out.

P.S. I have no stake in SlickRun, I just like it :)

Comment: sounds a lot like a beefed up variant on an App I already use.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know of any software that can do this for you automatically.

However, can't you trigger the updates through a console SVN task? If so, can't this be done by creating a batch file? It's low tech, and you might want to add a few pauses between each task, but it should do what you want.

Comment: TortoiseSVN doesn't come with a console interface and while I can use one, I'd rather not have to install it (I've had issues with mixed versions of SVN clients before)

Answer (score 1):

As you mention TortoiseSVN, I'll assume your O/S is windows.

You could launch an [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script at startup. I don't think it can easily detect HDD activity, but you can at least wait until each window appears with the [WinWaitActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) command.

Answer (score 0):

If each application has an average time they take to complete, you could simply use Windows' Scheduled Tasks application.  Obviously you'll need to be running Windows but Scheduled Tasks can be found in the Control Panel.

Execute "Add Schedules Task", select the program, the frequency and then the specific time.